# Format JSon so that mvc4 controller method can parse it

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-4

My controller Action:

```
       [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult H80Count(IEnumerable<H80SearchCriteria> model)
        {
             do some stuff and return Json;
        }
```

My model:

```
    public class H80SearchCriteria
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int Operator { get; set; }
        public string FieldID { get; set; }
        public string Kriterie { get; set; }

    }
```

My Javascript:

```
    var SearchCriteria = [];
    var i = 0;
    $('#tableSearchValues > tbody').find('tr').each(function () {
        i += 1;

        var row = {
            ID : i,
            Operator : $(this).data('operator'),
            FieldID : $(this).data('fieldid'),
            Kriterie: $(this).data('kriterie')
        };

        SearchCriteria.push(row);
    });
    var url = '/MyController/H80Count';
    var data = JSON.stringify(SearchCriteria) ;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
    etc...
```

The Json that is passed looks like this:

```
[{"ID":1,"Operator":1,"FieldID":1,"Kriterie":11211},{"ID":2,"Operator":1,"FieldID":1,"Kriterie":11211}]
```

I can't see why it is not parsed correctly. What am I missing?

Comment: JSON lint says that it's valid JSON. Perhaps you're looking for the wrong error? What kind of error message are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot the `contentType: 'application/json'` on ajax function.

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead of `IEnumerable` use array and place `[FromUri]` or `[FromBody]` which looks for values in the Uri or Body of the request.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult H80Count([FromUri] H80SearchCriteria[] model)
    {
         do some stuff and return Json;
    }
```

and dont forget to set the traditional ajax settings as true

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        traditional: true
        });
```